# Heat map visualization issue Microstrategy VI

Tags: data-visualization, heatmap, dashboard, microstrategy

I am creating a Dashboard using as a visualization a heat map. Everything was OK until I changed the parameters of my metric, the chart disappeared and I've got this message: 'Filter excludes all data'

[image]

The only modification that I've done is to set the Include Distinct Elements to true within the Count Parameter option of the metric.

[image]

What could be happening?. Do I need to set another parameter to get the count of distinct elements that I need?

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

surely the metric is level with some attribute that is not inside the visualization, if the filter has date for example, include it in the visualization.

Answer (score 0):

**"Filter Excludes All data"** is a default warning message that you will get in MicroStrategy when a reports/visuals/dashboards does not return any data.

https://community.microstrategy.com/s/article/KB47557-How-to-Properly-Suppress-the-Message-Filter-excludes-all?r=1&Component.reportDeprecationUsages=1&Headline.getInitData=1&ArticleView.getArticleHeaderDetail=1&Quarterback.validateRoute=1&RecordGvp.getRecord=1&ArticleRichContent.getArticleAuthor=1&ArticleTopicList.getTopics=1&ArticleRichContent.hasArticleAccess=1&ForceCommunityFeed.getModel=1&ArticleRichContent.getTopicsAssigned=1

There are n number of reasons for a report which cannot return data, please check the following steps to debug the issue,

1. As per your first image it shows a date range as filter, after you have changed to "Include only distinct" this date range might get affected so please put the objects in grid and apply the date filter and check whether it returns the correct data.
2. If it returns, check whether all the metrics returns a value.
3. Check whether candidateID, date and people attributes/metrics are properly related.

These steps will show, where the problem is, still if you could not figure it out export the dashboard and share it with MicroStrategy Tech Support team for debugging.

Hope it helps.